# How to deploy a R application that uses gWidgets and scripts?

Tags: r, deployment

I developed an application made of three scripts calling each other and that generates a basic GUI with `gWidgets`and uses lot of libraries.

I was wondering how to deploy this and make sure that the libraries are installed on the client machine.

Thanks

Comment: Uhhh. That isn't so easy, though you could write as a package with listed dependencies. Then when installed the package manager can handle the task of installation of necessary packages. If you use a github repository, `devtools` can make this all a one liner for your user without you having to wrangle a package through CRAN.

Comment: @jverzani Once again, thank you for your help but could you make a slightly more elaborated answer to be sure that is clear ?

Comment: The best way to ensure a user has the necessary additional  packages is to have them installed by the package manager. This means, you put your code into a package, specify the dependencies in the DESCRIPTION file, and have the user install that. If you don't want your work on CRAN, then you can have your users take advantage of the alternative means to install packages provided in `devtools`, such as installing from a GitHub repo.